# Can I set up Outlook to only send email for some account, but not receive its messages?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Due to some changes in our company, one of my colleagues wants to send emails using a colleague's email address, but not receive any emails.  When I configure Outlook with an IMAP account, I'm prompted for both incoming and outgoing servers.

How do I set up Outlook to only send, but not receive emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlook has Send and Receive Groups, with appropriate checkboxes to enable and disable Incoming and Outgoing options when you do a Send and Receive.

I don't have Outlook installed on this machine, but it's under the Accounts area, or Tools menu on older versions.

Answer (score -1):

Select the "Send/Receive" Tab within Outlook
select "Send/Receive Groups" drop down Menu
Select "Define Send/Receive Groups"
Click Edit
Select Each configured account then uncheck "Receive mail items" under Account Options.

Comment: In what way is this different from the existing answer?