# How can I set up Outlook 2010 to send emails but not receive new emails?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using Outlook 2010 and cannot get around the problem of just being able to send with one e-mail account and not receive all e-mail sent to that e-mail.

It is basically the same question as: [Can I set up Outlook to only send email for some account, but not receive its messages?](https://superuser.com/questions/219164/can-i-set-up-outlook-to-only-send-email-for-some-account-but-not-receive-its-me)

I have tried to set up Send/Receive groups by just selecting "Send mail items" and not Receive mail items" under the Account options inside the "Send/Receive Settings" for this particular account - do however still receive all e-mails.

Does anyone have a clue how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this in your Send/Receive group configuration. Open the Send/Receive Groups dialog by pressing the CTRL+ALT+S keyboard shortcut or as an alternative use;

#### Outlook 2007 and previous;

```
Tools -> Options... -> tab Mail Setup -> button Send/Receive...
```

#### Outlook 2010;

```
Send/Receive (tab) -> Send/Receive Groups (button) -> Define Send/Receive Groups...
```

In the Send/Receive Groups dialog press the `Edit...` button.

In the left section, select the account for which you want to modify the send/receive settings.

In the Account Options section you can disable the option for “Receive mail items”.

Press the OK button until you have closed all open dialogs.

[image: the panel]